# WiFi often not working after suspend on ubuntu 20.04

Tags: networking, 20.04, suspend

My WiFi connection regularly does not work after suspending Ubuntu 20.04. I had a similar problem with Ubuntu 18.04 but then I could always run

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

and it would work again. However this does not work anymore since I've installed Ubuntu 20.04. I followed the wireless network troubleshooter guide on the ubuntu website. I tried to connect to a different network (phone hotspot) and I tried some of the the opposed solutions I could find in related questions like

```
sudo nmcli radio wifi off
```

and

```
sudo mncli radio wifi on
```

or

```
sudo systemctl enable wifi-resume.service
```

Nothing works so far. The problem occurs about half the time I suspend my laptop or close and open the lid. The only solution I have now is to reboot or suspend and unsuspend ubuntu again.

Any thoughts on possible solutions here?

Comment: can you run `ifconfig`, `route -n`, `ping 8.8.8.8` commands and post the output of them? another question is are you connected via cable or just wifi?

Comment: Try this solution for wifi going to sleep: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1022203/how-to-prevent-wifi-sleep-after-suspend

Comment: I think some update fixed this for me, it just stopped being a problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

i have this issue as well

i wrote this script and use it when it happen

```
#!/bin/bash

sudo nmcli networking off
sudo nmcli networking on
```