# When I suspend my Surface Pro 4, its wifi remains turned off and never gets turned back on until I restart this laptop

Tags: networking, suspend

I have a Surface Pro 4 with Windows installed alongside Ubuntu. I don't use any external wifi adapter. My internal adapter is Marvell Technology Group Ltd. 88w8897 [AVASTAR] 8.02.11ac Wireless, and my driver is mwifiex_pcie.

I tried wifi power saving, and I don't know if I did it correctly, `chmod a+x /lib/systemd/system-sleep/iwlwifi-reset` (it was with very long text, I made mwifiex_pcie-reset and chmod) according to the instructions [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1022203/how-to-prevent-wifi-sleep-after-suspend).

Comment: it's okay when i just once suspend it, but twice with out restart(=rebooting) then it cannot connect to wifi before restarting