# How to prevent Hotspot sleep after suspend?

Tags: 22.04, network-manager, suspend, hot-spot

I want hotspot to be always on even when my PC is on suspend. Usually when I suspend my PC which runs on Ubuntu 22.04LTS, hotspot gets turned off. I tried methods given here "https://askubuntu.com/questions/1022203/how-to-prevent-wifi-sleep-after-suspend" but it didn't work. Is there any other way?

Comment: There is no way.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to keep a hotspot working wile the PC is suspended, because CPU is stopped.

It doesn't depend on an OS.

The question you referred to is about a case when Wi-Fi doesn't start after a PC is waken up after suspend.