# Wifi does not connect after resuming laptop from suspend Ubuntu 22.04 - dual boot

Tags: 20.04, wireless, 22.04

I have recently installed ubuntu 22.04 alongside windows 10. Whenever my laptop goes on sleep/suspend while using ubuntu and I resume it, I am unable to connect wifi. I have tried setting wifi power off as follows;

```
sudo nano /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf
```

and changing `wifi.powersave = 3` to `wifi.powersave = 2`.

But it did not work although many people accepted these solutions:

- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/269661/how-to-turn-off-wireless-power-management-permanently
- [How to prevent wifi sleep after suspend](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1022203/how-to-prevent-wifi-sleep-after-suspend)

I also tried restating the service as follow: `sudo service network-manager restart`, but no luck!

Can anyone please help me to fix this issue as I have to restart my laptop to connect wifi if it goes on sleep/suspend.

Comment: Please detail what you have tried so no one wastes time telling you to try something you have already tried. Edit the question to add this info and not in comments.

Comment: @David, thanks updated my original question!